# Alignment issue in the developer story - story view

Tags: feature-request, design, developer-story

In Developer Story, after adding our preferred sites under the 
"Pick the network sites you want to display", there is an alignment issue in  the [Story view](https://stackoverflow.com/users/story/current?view=Timeline).

The site icon is not centralized with the site reputation. Can this be aligned correctly?

> [image: Developer story]